# add an ID attribute to < input type="text" > that is dynamically being assigned with and api using Javascript/$Jquery

Tags: jquery, text, types, attributes

We are using an API from MapBox for the activity map on our site. We are also using another API to bring in weather from OpenWeatherMap.

We are using both on the same page and the  filed I am using for the Open Weather map was made by me and was not brought in dynamically from the API like the content we receive from mapBox. the  filed from Map Box is brought in and we do not have control of how it presents to the page

Since both API calls are on the same page. I have attempted to no prevail to add the id we are using (id=" location ") to the input filed

any suggestions on how we will be able to add this to​ this field would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Replace selector with your selector. Jquery attr() helps to add attributes dynamically

```
$('selector').attr('id', 'location');
```